# Django json nested list .get()

Tags: django, django-views

I am stuck with a silly problem.

I have a json data and trying to save it in my model.

Here is the code.

```
response = response.json() #this gives json data
response = json.loads(response) #loads string to json           
json_string = response #ready to get data from list
modelfielda = json_string.get("abc") # this works fine
modelfieldb = json_string.get('["c"]["d"]["e"]') #this does not give data though data is present.
```

My json data comes like this:

```
{  
   "abc":"AP003",
   "c":[  
      {  
         "d":{  
            "e":"some data",
            "f":"some data"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So my question is how to get data inside `c`.

Comment: What about `bnm = json_string.get('c')`?

Comment: @Chiefir That will give full list and not specific item in e.

Comment: Try this for e -> `bnm = json_string.get('c').get('d').get('e')`

Comment: @Chiefir, note that `c` is a list

Comment: @Chiefir It worked thanks.

Comment: @soon, aha, then it is bnm = json_string.get('c')[0].get('d').get('e')

Comment: Post that as answer, I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using **multiple `.get`s**:

```
bnm = json_string.get('c')[0].get('d').get('e')  # bnm = 'some data'
```

Or perhaps better (since it will error in case the key does not exists):

```
bnm = json_string['c'][0]['d']['e']  # bnm = 'some data'
```

Since you converted it to a Python dictionary, you basically work with a dictionary, and you can obtain the value corresponding to a key by using `some_dict[some_key]`. Since we here have a cascade of dictionaries, we thus obtain the subdictionary for which we again obtain the corresponding value. The value corresponding to `c` is a list, and we can obtain the *first* element by writing `[0]`.

Comment: The answer is correct for my question. But in case there are multiple list inside c, one has to manually use [0] or there is any short code for that. Thanks

Comment: @SapnaSharma: well the question is what do you want to do with that lists? Return *all* elements, only the *first* one, but indeed, you should add `[0]`, or we can write a function that solves the logic.

Answer (score 2):

Try this for `e`:
`bnm = json_string.get('c').get('d').get('e')`
 or with list:
`bnm = json_string.get('c')[0].get('d').get('e')`